# Normalized Histogram by counting the number of observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data has three different variables and I am trying to plot the 3 different histograms using R and ggplot2. I found that you can normalize this data by using y=..count../sum(..count..) as an aes option. However, this does not normalize it the way I want. Instead I want to divide ..count.. by the number of observations per variable. However, while two of my variables have the same number of observations, my last one does not. The first two variables have 10700 observations while the third one has 20000 observations.

I can produce the correct histograms if I separate the two variables but I would like to create them together so I can compare them properly. Below is the working code for only two of my variables.

```
ggplot(data = melt(data_go), mapping = aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../10600),breaks = seq(0,10,by = 1)) + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x')
```

My data looks like the table below and I use the first line of code to make the histograms in R. This creates three different histograms per variable (which is correct).

```
ggplot(data = melt(data_go), mapping = aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)),breaks = seq(1,10,by = 1)) + facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x')

                            name     variable       value
1 Xetrov90024587m.L|Xelaev18044347m Avg_18_L_  0.90018700
2             emb.L|Xelaev18008312m Avg_18_L_  0.15418752
3 Xetrov90018247m.L|Xelaev18034878m Avg_18_L_  0.56432320
4          elmod1.L|Xelaev18003296m Avg_18_L_  0.07647218
5            pygm.L|Xelaev18026582m Avg_18_L_ 35.58034000
6            smu1.L|Xelaev18006121m Avg_18_L_ 65.81906000
```

TLDR: How do I count the number of observations there are per variable and use it in a command to create normalized histograms with it (count/num of observations)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this lines, though your mileage may vary as it is not clear to me what your datasets look like

```
ggplot(data=melt(data_go)) + stat_count(mapping = aes(x=value, y=..prop.., group=1), width=.2)+
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = 'free_x')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! My data sets are csv files that are organized (when open in excel) as 4 columns, the first being the name (irrelevant to the histogram), the second and third being the data values with the 10700 observations each, and the fourth column being the data values with 20000 observations. The way they are formatted in R as a data frame is the name being the first column and the variable as the title of the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th column so whatever variable it is. The last is the value I'm making a histogram from.

Comment: Actually this does not work with my data I would like to keep using geom_histogram instead. y=..prop.. seems correct but it does not plot anything.